# Spring-cloud-gateway and oauth2 (keycloak), forward user informations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on a microservice application with a gateway service using spring-cloud-gateway. I use Keycloak to handle authentication. I want to forward the user informations from keycloak to the other services but I have some trouble with Filters.

I think that I could add it to the query parameters but I don't know how. I also do not realy know how to get the user informations in my gateway microservice.

My application.yml :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
      routes:
        - id: id_1
          uri: http://localhost:10102/
          predicates:
            - Path=/id_1/**
        - id: id_2
          uri: http://localhost:10103/
          predicates:
            - Path=/id_2/**
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm
```

My security config :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You mean you want to forward the user information grabbed from keycloak? Are the services defined as keycloak clients?

Comment: Yes that's it. Only the Gateway Service, should I defined all of them as keycloak clients ?

Comment: That would be your best bet I guess. Then you just proxy-pass the Authorization header and you can grab the user info for any of the services.